# How to programmatically set IsChecked property on ListboxItem?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a listbox, which I fill with a list via ItemsSource = list.

Now, I have another list. And what I want to do is loop through the ListBox, to see if the ListBoxItem.Name is the same. If so, then the ListBoxItem should be selected.

My idea:

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>();
List<string> secondList = new List<string>();

Listboxx.ItemsSource = firstList;

foreach (string striing in secondList)
{
   foreach (ListBoxItem iitem in Listboxx)
   {
       if (striing == iitem.Name)
       {
          iitem.IsSelected = true;
       }
   }
 }
```

Or is there a way in the ListboxItemTemplate to set the IsChecked bool to {Binding IsCheckedOrNot}?

Answer (score 2):

Nested loops generally should be avoided when possible. Why not do something like this?

```
foreach(var iitem in Listboxx.Items.Where(i => secondList.Contains(i.Name)))
{
    iitem.IsSelected = true;
}
```